# Transferring Cell Values Between Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am needing to transfer cell values from one Worksheet to another. However, the cells do not align with each other. Sheet 19 cells do not align with Sheet 47 cells. I have used the following code to transfer values in the past using a Colon. But, when I use a comma, the transfer does not work. Sheet19 cell "G76" is to remain blank.

```
    Sheet19.Range("F76,H76").Value = Sheet47.Range("I3,J3").Value 'To - From
```

Comment: Sheet19.Range("F76:H76").Value = Sheet47.Range("I3:J3").Value ?

Comment: Use 2 lines `Sheet19.Range("F76").Value = Sheet47.Range("I3").Value : Sheet19.Range("H76").Value = Sheet47.Range("J3").Value`

Comment: I should have been clearer in my description. I do want Sheet19 "G76" to remain blank. I tried using the code you suggested, but it fills "G76" with Sheet47 "J3".

Comment: CDP1802, thank you for your response. I was hoping there was a shorter way of doing so, I have several cells needing to be copied to.

Comment: Show the more complex case you have. How many cells, are both to and from non-contiguous ranges

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Values With Discontinuous Ranges

- You need to copy cell by cell because whatever you copy, can end up only in a continuous (single-area) range.

```vb
Sub CopyCellValues()

    Const SRC_ADDRESSES As String = "I3,J3"
    Const DST_ADDRESSES As String = "F76,H76"

    Dim sAddr() As String: sAddr = Split(SRC_ADDRESSES, ",")
    Dim dAddr() As String: dAddr = Split(DST_ADDRESSES, ",")
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(sAddr)
        Sheet19.Range(dAddr(n)).Value = Sheet47.Range(sAddr(n)).Value
    Next n

    MsgBox "Values copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```